# Why OAuth2 Not Use Access_Token & Secret

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I don't understand the necessity of `authorization_code`, all the answers are because of the URL is not safe. But now use `code & secret` to get `access_token`, then get user sources. Why not get access_token from client, then use `access_token & secret` to get user sources on backend server. Even the attacker get the `access_token`， `secret` in the backend server, attacker can't get it.

Answer (score 0):

The Authorization Code Grant type is the most commonly used because it is optimized for server-side applications, where source code is not publicly exposed, and Client Secret confidentiality can be maintained.

This is a redirection-based flow, which means that the application must be capable of interacting with the user-agent (i.e. the user's web browser) and receiving API authorization codes that are routed through the user-agent.

This is 2 steps authorization process:

1. The user's web browser will initiate authentication/authorization. After authentication/authorization, the authorization server will send the authrorization_code to the client server (backend server) using redirect_url callback.
2. Now backend server can use authrorization_code to get the access_token and refresh_token without exposing the token to the external world.